# MDX Compare DateTime attribute

Tags: datetime, compare, mdx

I´m new to MDX and I have a simple question. I work with the TFS Cube it is named as Team System. My problem:

I have an IIF expression where I want to check additional my expression with an AND operator. There I want to compare two DateTime objects. The report should only show me the data from the actual date. Here my code:

```
IIF(ISEMPTY(SUM(YTD(
    [Work Item].[PlannedWeek__HierarchyByWeek].CurrentMember),
    [Measures].[EffectivelyValue]))
```

**AND[Work Item].[PlannedWeek__HierarchyByWeek].CurrentMember < Now()**

```
 , [Measures].[EffectivelyValue]
  , SUM(YTD(
   [Work Item].[PlannedWeek__HierarchyByWeek].CurrentMember),
    [Measures].[EffectivelyValue]) )
```

Planned Week is a self created field which has the DateTime datatype. The Now() function has also a DateTime datatype so the comparision should be right but it happens nothing.

Thanking you in anticipation

Eugen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hierarchy members in MDX have a data type of 'member', and do not have a 'primitive' data type like datetime, string, or integer. Only member properties have 'primitive' data types. You could either define a property like `datetime` of your week attribute. Assuming you are SQL Server Analysis Services, this would be done via relationships.

Or you could use string operations to extract the date information from the `UniqueName` property which avoids having to change the cube. The UniqueName contains the data that you defined as the key in your cube design. Assuming your week hierarchy members have a key from which you can extract something like 20130820 for August 20, 3013 via string functions (I just will use `Mid(, 30, 8)` as an example below), you could do something like

```
CLng(Mid([Work Item].[PlannedWeek__HierarchyByWeek].CurrentMember.UniqueName, 30, 8))
<
CLng(Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd"))
```

You will have to check what exactly the `CurrentMember.UniqueName` shows in your cube to adapt the above code.

And finally, you could of course also use string methods to extract the relevant parts from the UniqueName and then the `CDate` function on that to compare to an unchanged `Now()`, i. e. do all operations on the left side of the `<`.

Answer (score 1):

Hello thank you very much for you answer. I tried:

```
Mid([Work Item].[xxxx_PlannedWeek__HierarchyByWeek].CurrentMember.UniqueName,58,10)
```

shows e.g. 2013-07-21, 2013-07-28   (it shows the week endings)

so I tried this:

```
AND  CLng(Mid([Work Item].[xxxx_PlannedWeek__HierarchyByWeek].CurrentMember.UniqueName,58,10))
<CLng(Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

But it happens nothing. If I execute it in a single way it shows everywhere "true". But I have datasets with dates which are e.g. > 2013-08-23. So there should be false values too.

EDIT: OK I solved the problem. The

```
Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

must be

```
Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd")
```